# vsts build fails on Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-identity, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Got a git project hosten in VSTS. When i trigger a build in VSTS it fails stating the following:

> You must add a reference to assembly
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework, Version=2.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.

The reference is the nuget package for aspnet identity and the project builds (rebuild solution) just fine in VS2015 on my local pc. There are of course no local changes and the same branche is build.

Can anyone tell me why this happens or point me in a direction on how to solve this.

Comment: Some problem with package.config? Retrieve the sources into a new directory and execute a rebuild checking for errors.

Comment: Just take another look in the VS2015 Nuget packagemanager. The package did not show up for the project causing the problem, but the dll was included in the references somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open Package Manager Console view in VS 2015 (View=>Other Window=>Package Manager Console)
2. Run Update-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework in Package Manager Console
3. Build project in local
4. Commit and push changes (the files in package folder could not commit and push to server)
5. Add NuGet Installer build step (Installation type: Restore) to your build definition (top of other steps) to restore package
6. Queue build